# How can I replicate in my bd server from .NET using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a data model on LINQ in my project which I generated from a DB on SQL Server. The problem is that all the changes that I make only have effect in the Local DB on my project but not in the web SQL server, how can I replicate the changes automatically?

Comment: You read from one server and wish to write to another serve?  Normally data you wish to update is read, processed and updated to the same server.  LINQ has nothing to do with that process other than being a tool you are using.  Please post the code you have that reproduces the issue and where your challenge lies.

Answer (score 0):

To sync your schema you have to use a tool like Visual studio 2010 database projects

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/02/vs-2010-database-project-an-introduction.aspx

or

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm

Or you have to manually do it.